# Mix Levels for iPad 

Tags: ipad, mixing

I've been asked to do a mix on a short advert that will be shown to potential clients on an ipad. This version will not be broadcast and is strictly going to be used as promo material to be played via the ipads. I have no info on how they will listen to the audio (headphones or through the ipads speakers?), but I'm just wondering at what RMS and Peak levels I should aim my mix at?

Answer (score 2):

I've done a few iPad mixes quite successfully. The speaker is pretty nice compared to the iPhone or blackberry. Obviously keep in mind low freq as a lot of that won't come across. If you keep your overall mix around or below 85 LeQ(M) set your L1 to -0.4 and things should be peachy. Best thing is to mic test on the device and make notes then make adjustments. Keep things well balanced as if mixing for Internet and stay within a minimized dynamic range and test your mix. Oh

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I run Airfoil, which allows me to stream sound directly from my DAW to the iPad.  There's a few seconds latency, so it doesn't work for video sync work, but for quickly checking a mix or checking to see how a sound effect is going to sound on the device, while you tweak levels or EQ, it's excellent.  I find myself using it in the same way a music mix studio will quickly check their mixes on a pair of NS-10s or Auratones.